# Why does the spawn'ed objects not have the correct name & tag

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I use the following code to spawn prefabs:

```
public override void OnStartServer() {

    // LOAD THE MASTER LIST
    foreach (string anObject in nameList) {

        temp_GameObject = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("_BackSide")) as GameObject;
        temp_GameObject.name = anObject;
        temp_GameObject.tag = anObject;

        NetworkServer.Spawn (temp_GameObject);

    }
}
```

Also tried the following with the same result:

```
public override void OnStartClient () {
    temp_GameObject = Resources.Load ("_BackSide") as GameObject;
    temp_GameObject.name = "Zappa";
    Instantiate (temp_GameObject);
    NetworkServer.Spawn (temp_GameObject);
}
```

It works perfectly on the host/client side and the names & tags are correct. However, on the client/client side all prefabs are spawned but with the same name, "_BackSide", and the same tag for each prefabs.

Could someone nice please give me a hint of what is it i am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you may need to set the tags within a `[ClientRpc]` function.

Comment: Thanks Wafer, tried that but could not get it to work. :-(

Comment: Maybe I've mixed it up, have you tried `[Command]`?

Comment: If you still need help, this explains it https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html.

Comment: Thanks, I have read that but maybe i missed something. Will read that again.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?